# Custom Task assigned to multiple users in SP 2010

Tags: list, workflow, tasks

I have a first SharePoint List that contains two columns:

- Name of the application
- Name(s) of the developer(s)

There is a second SharePoint List that fires a Sequential Workflow in Visual Studio 2010. That list is about Problems with the applications (ie: An Error with the application "Blabla").

When a problem is added, The workflow will assign a single task to the developer(s) of the application that has en error.

If the application concerns more than one person, I would like that there is a single task that is assigned to them. If one of them complete it, the tasks would be also completed for the others.

I have managed to assign the task to a single person, but I am not sure how to make it works when there is multiples users assigned to the same application.

I have made some searches and it seems that it is not possible with SP 2007 but I am not sure about SP 2010.
The only way is to create group programmatically with these users in it when the workflow is fired, and to delete it when the workflow ends. The second workaround is maybe to have a group with theses users instead of using a SharePoint List but I would prefer to use a SharePoint List.

by using Replicator, I think it would make multiples tasks that are independant from each other, so it is not good.

Is there another solution?

Answer (score 1):

I tried this using SPD 2010 "Start Custom Task Process" and assign it to a group of users. Once any person belonged to that group completes the task, it automatically proceeds to another task if there is any.

PS: Check the checkbox on the general settings of the task process to "Only allow task recipients and process owners to read and edit workflow tasks"

GL :)

Comment: I know I can assign a task to a group that contains users. But I cannot assign it to multiple users. If I add a new task from SP2010, I can assign a task [to multiple users such like this](http://s8.postimage.org/ge7gyoodh/image.png) but I can't do it programmatically